# move_upoaded_file():failed to open stream: permission denied laravel xampp

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, windows-7

I am having this error "move_upoaded_file():failed to open stream: permission denied" but not every time when a person uploads the file more than 2 to 3 times then this error appears. Here is my code for uploading the file

```
    $Editorfilepath = $ProjectPath . "\\Editor\\" . $WriterName . "\\" . $WriterUploadedDate . "\\" . $FileName;
if(file_exists($Editorfilepath)) {
    unlink($Editorfilepath); //remove the previous file
}
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["delWorkingFile"]["tmp_name"], $Editorfilepath);
$DeliveryDirectoryPath = $ProjectPath . "\\Delivery\\" . $WriterName;
```

Comment: You should change permission directory and set it to 777,

Comment: which directory? application directory or files directory in which files are saving?

Answer (score 0):

> 

change permission

sudo chmod 777 path folder